# Should the [immigration] tag be merged as a synonym for [immigration-law]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

At the time of writing, **[immigration](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration)** is [tagged to 284 questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration), and **[immigration-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration-law)** is [tagged to 28](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration-law).

Despite the former being tagged to significantly more questions, should it be merged as a synonym for the latter for consistency with other [xxx-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xxx-law) tags?

(Unless the community's consensus shows otherwise, I suggest the [illegal-immigration](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illegal-immigration) tag remain as category in its own right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

I agree that [immigration](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration) should be merged with [immigration-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration-law).

Answer (score 0):

[support](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support)

I see this is marked [status-completed](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) but the tags were merged the opposite way round to the suggested synonymisation that sought consistency with other [xxx-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xxx-law) tag formats.

Was this deliberate?